# How do I vertcally align thumbnails of unknown height using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, vertical-alignment

Ok, I am a complete beginner to this, in fact I am still building my first website. I am attempting to do this all by hand-coding without a CMS in order to try and learn as much possible as quickly as possible. If this post is in the wrong place I apologise, and a pointer to right place would be appreciated.

Here goes, I am trying to piece together a bit of jQuery that will automatically vertically align my thumbnails in my image gallery (they are all different sizes). They are within fixed size div's and the function I am attempting looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#ul.photo).bind(function() {

var smartVert=$(this);

var phty=ob.("ul.photo img").height(); //get height  of photos

var phtdif=Math.floor(208 - phty); //subtract height of photo from div height

var phttop=Math.floor(phtdif / 2); //gets padding reqd.

$ob.("ul.photo").css({'padding-top' : phttop}) //sets padding to center thumbnail

});

smartVert();

</script>
```

Unsurprisingly this doesn't work, if some kindly soul could take pity on a total noob, and point out where I am going wrong (probably in writing complete gibberish would be my first guess), it would be greatly appreciated - even if you could just point me in the direction of a tutorial regarding these things. I have looked and found one reference that said such a function was easy to create, but it did not elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[made some code here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/52nmx/2/)

for example:

html

```
<div id="yourdiv">
    <img height="200" width="100" src="x" />
    <img height="100" width="100" src="x" />
    <img height="150" width="100" src="x" />
    <img height="300" width="100" src="x" />
</div>​
```

css

```
#yourdiv {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}
#yourdiv img {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $yourdiv = $("#yourdiv");
    var divHeight = $yourdiv.height();

    $("img",$yourdiv).each(function() {
        var imgElement = $(this);
        var imgPadding = (Math.floor((divHeight-imgElement.height()) / 2));
        imgElement.css('margin-top',imgPadding+'px');
    });
});​
```

​

​
edit:

for better aligning: set your images to block and float them left. then clearfix your div.

edit 2:

looping through an set of objects with a for-loop is faster than using `.each`

Comment: Thankyou, but I am trying to use variable image-sizes within a liquid layout. It may be that this turns out to be way beyond me, but other than this vertical alignment issue it seems to be coming together nicely............

I do really appreciate your taking the time to answer me by the way, was a bit afraid I'd get chewed out for not knowing anything like I did on another forum

Comment: Scratch that....Boss just told me he wants pictures as backgrounds..liquid layout out of the window. would still be interested in whether it is possible though...

Comment: Wow, it works. Thankyou very much, sorry it was my inexperience and crap knowledge tht led me to thnk it didn't....forgot to change "#yourdiv" to ".yourdiv".
My apologies..and seriously, thankyou

Comment: Amazingly helpful. All the dumb CSS hacks/workarounds/whatever which only work in certain cases were making me sick anyway. Your solution is working as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$('#ul.photo')` contains multiple `<img>` tags:

```
 $('#ul.photo img').each(function() {
   var $img = $(this);
   $img.css('padding-top', (208 - $img.height()));
 });
```

Comment: thankyou, I appreciate your taking the time to answer my question, however I don't think that I explained myself properly. Sorry. Have a look at my comment above for a better explanation (I think!).

Answer (score 0):

here is the css for my gallery:

```
.contentphoto {
    position:relative;
         width:64%
    margin:auto;
    left:10.375em;
    top:-36.625em;
    background-color: #7EC0EE;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    z-index:1;
}

ul.gallery{
    width: 100%; 
    padding-left: 3.2em;
    margin:  0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;           /*Set default width*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: inline;
}

.photo {
    height: 13em;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-right: 10px;  /*Creates the 10px gap */
    padding: 20px;
    background: #e3e1d5;
}

.photo img {        /*Flexible image size with border*/
         width: 89%;    /*Took 1% off of the width for IE6 bug*/
         padding: 5%;
    background:#fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```

sorry for putting this in another answer box but the comment button stopped working...